# Finding weekday with specific date

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I am learning python and going through some interactive exercises.  Specifically, I'm working on [Friday the 13th](https://www.hackinscience.org/exercises/friday-the-13th).

I have rewritten several iterations of this but can never seem to lock it down.  With this version, it seems to get hung up when run with the simulated start date of 2025-06-12 which means there's a problem with the "this month" section.  Since it returns an accurate Friday the 13th except not 2025-06-13, I suspect it's a problem with the `elif` statement, particularly the

```
and date.fromisoformat(current_year + '-' + current_month + '-13').weekday == 4:
```

Here's the most recent iteration of this.

```
def friday_the_13th():
    from datetime import date
    current_year = str(date.today().year)
    current_month = str(date.today().month)
    if len(current_month) == 1: current_month = '0' + current_month
#Function to increment to the 13th of next month
    def NextMonth13(startdate):
        lst_date = str(startdate)
        lst_date = lst_date.split('-')
        month = int(lst_date[1])
        if month == 12:
            year = str(int(lst_date[0]) + 1)
            month = '01'
            return str(year + '-' + month + '-' + '13')
        else:
            year = lst_date[0]
            month = str(month + 1)
            if len(month) == 1: month = '0' + month
            return str(year + '-' + month + '-' + '13')
# Return today if today is Friday the 13th
    if date.today().weekday() == 4 and date.today().day == 13:
        return date.today()
# Check if this month's 13th is in the future and if it's a Friday
    elif date.today().day < 13 and date.fromisoformat(current_year + '-' + current_month + '-13').weekday == 4:
        return str(date.fromisoformat(current_year + '-' + current_month + '-13'))
#Check next month and return result if Friday 13
    else:
        result = NextMonth13(date.today())
        while not (date.fromisoformat(result).weekday() == 4):
            result = NextMonth13(result)
            if date.fromisoformat(result).weekday() == 4:
                return result
```

Would someone mind giving me some guidance on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do everything strictly in terms of `datetime.date` instances. Starting with the current month and year, see if the 13th is a Friday, if it is and that date is less the today, you're done. Otherwise iteratively check the 13th of the successive months until you encounter one that's a Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your error is that you forgot the parenthesis after the `weekday` method call: `date.fromisoformat(current_year + '-' + current_month + '-13').weekday() == 4` (FYI, `date.fromisoformat(current_year + '-' + current_month + '-13').weekday` returns the memory address of the method, something like this `<built-in method weekday of datetime.date object at 0x7fa4e36058f0>`. As you can see, it is nowhere near the result you were expecting, so it was normal for your program to behave this way.)

Second, you are needlessly complicating yourself by doing `str` conversions all the time:

```py
def friday_the_13th():
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    days_passed = 0
    today = datetime.today()
    while True:
        curr = today + timedelta(days=days_passed)
        if curr.day == 13 and datetime.weekday(curr) == 4:
            return str(datetime.date(curr))
        days += 1
```

This is more readable and less prone to error as you only convert to string at the end, after you've handled all your calculations.

Comment: Ok, good point.  In trying to understand your example, everything makes sense to me except for the  `curr = today + timedelta(days=days)`.  Does the timedelta need "days=days"?  If so, can you help me understand that...it's the only thing I don't get.

Comment: I changed my variable name for comprehension. Here the `days` is the name of the argument for the function, while `days_passed` is my variable, which contains the value I want to pass to the function. This function has a couple of arguments you can pass (`days`, `seconds`, `microseconds`, `milliseconds`, `minutes`, `hours` and `weeks`), so you have to indicate which parameter you want to give. If I wanted to increment by weeks, I'd have done `timedelta(weeks = <variable_name>)`. Hope this clears out your doubts!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but to calculate the future Friday 13th you can do something like:

```
import datetime

def get_13th_future(startdate, months):
    result=[]
    year=startdate.year
    month=startdate.month
    checkdate = datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=13)
    for i in range(month):
        if checkdate.weekday()==4:
            result.append(checkdate.isoformat())
        month+=1
        if month==13:
            year+=1
            month=1
        checkdate=datetime.date(year=year,month=month,day=13)
    return result

startdate=datetime.datetime.now()
print(get_13th_future(startdate,1000))
```

If you like to search for a specific date you might construct a set instead of the list.

Comment: Note that the OP is not supposed to define a parameter 'months', so you might want to use a `while True` that returns if the desired date is found. Also, you don't check the current date.

Comment: The note is right. I just wanted to give an idea how quick we can find all Friday 13th in a time range. It's not perfect and it is not targeting only the next date or checking given `startdate`. But all this can be achieved by simple modifications.